# MySQL --server-id in MySQL 5.7 sets what value, if we omitted the server id.

Tags: mysql

If you omit --server-id, the default ID is 0, in which case the master refuses connections from all slaves, and slaves refuse to connect to the master. 
In MySQL 5.6, whether the server ID is set to 0 explicitly or the default is allowed to be used, the server sets the server_id system variable to 1. 
This is a known issue in MySQL 5.6 but it is fixed in MySQL 5.7.

How it was fixed? Explain?

for Refernce: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_uuid

Answer (score 0):

What's "fixed" [in 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_id) is that the server no longer coerces 0 to 1.  It remains as 0 if set explicitly to 0 or if no value is specified.

...which is still a useless value.  The fix was just the consistency.

Each server still needs a unique `@@server_id` assigned between 1 and 2³²-1 for replication to work.

Comment: I have installed MySQL 5.6 and sets no server id in my.cnf, so by default it should take 0 value.

In MySQL 5.6, whether the server ID is set to 0 explicitly or the default is allowed to be used, the server sets the server_id system variable to 1.
But when i'm running the command in mysql

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| server_id     | 0     |
+---------------+-------+

It should be 1 according to above statement.
How come value 0?